# manipulating a stream via FILE*

Tags: c++

I've just run across some C++ code which uses a FILE* to manipulate a file stream using the "f" functions (fopen, fseek, fread, etc). I believe that these are provided by standard header cstdio.

Is this considered a dated or bad practice in modern C++ code? I ask because I also see that you can get/set the position of the stream of an ifstream object using setg and tellg and I'd like to know what the advantage is to doing it this way. Is this an "old habits die hard" C programmer way of manipulating the stream or is there still a valid reason to use FILE* and the "f" functions in modern C++ code?

Comment: This is very subjective.  The stream classes are not exactly C++'s finest moment.  But the only thing that matters is what your team has standardized on.  If you are a team of one then you get to pick.

Comment: I do have a choice since I'm working alone. I haven't seen much C code so I didn't recognize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are there for C compatibility, although there's nothing stopping you from using them in a modern C++ program.

Some people tend to prefer C streams because either they dislike the C++ streams (which are arguably quite a mess in many respects), or they think the C streams are faster. This last point was valid on many implementations few years ago, but on modern implementations C++ streams usually tend do be somewhat faster (this statement is based on some benchmarks I did on g++, YMMV).

Still, there's an important problem with C streams: since they are C stuff and aren't implemented in terms of classes, you must be extra careful when using them together with exceptions, otherwise you may leak file handles; this problem isn't relevant with C++ file streams since they are encapsulated in classes, whose destructor is called when an exception causes a stack unwind, so file handle leaking is prevented.

Comment: I've learned C++ from the start and never used C streams as far as I know so it's hard to compare. Based on the answers I'm seeing, it seems like I might just be better off sticking with ifstream.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, in C++, the correct way is to use *ifstream*. *cstdio*, as it name indicates, is for C compatibility only.

Both are correct though.

Answer (score 1):

For C++ the *iostream* library should be used in most cases.

The iostream library gives out in and output in a general way, and offers
type safety and is less error prone than the *cstdio*. Also the *iostream*
library offers extensibility, allowing you to inherit and overload to make
your own types streamable in addition to the standard types.

There are however some people that thinks that the *iostream* library are 
overly verbose, also some use the *cstdio* library because it is most familiar 
to them.

Some valid points exists to use the *cstdio* though. Most *iostream* implementations
are slower performance wise than the *cstdio* and there have conducted tests that 
show that a `cout` is slower than a `printf`.

So if speed is critical, or it is a mixed c++ and c code base, that might be an 
argument for chosing the *cstdio* library. Otherwise the standard io for c++ is
*iostream*

Answer (score 0):

In c++ you often prefer operating on streams. Makes life a bit easier when switching the file to a network stream (or any other kind of stream).

cstdio is, as stated, manly for c-compatibility but also the path to direct access and is still often found in code where people dislike the overhead of streams.